# CardView with transparent background issue on > API 21

Tags: android, transparency, android-cardview

I am building a CardView with a transparent background, and am running into an issue with trying to set the cardBackgroundColor to be one with an alpha channel.

Here is what I've tried:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_view_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/icon_bottom_margin"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#66F9F9F9"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"/>
```

The result is a CardView button that has no transparency what-so-ever (but with the F9F9F9 grey color, ignoring the 66 alpha value). So, next step was to try doing this programmatically:

```
mListBtn.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);
int baseColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.material_gray);
mListBtn.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50,
                Color.red(baseColor),
                Color.green(baseColor),
                Color.blue(baseColor)));
```

This is the result:

[image: problem img]

Notice there is a padding between the center and the border. The CardView is empty with no child views in it, and I tried this with/without the setPreventCornerOverlap() call to see if this was the issue... Can anybody explain why this is happening to me?

**1) Why does the XML definition of my CardView with cardBackgroundColor ignore alpha coloring**

**2) Why does setting the cardBackgroundColor programmatically cause the coloring to work, but now there is a padding implicitly added?**